# Giving specific pixels a certain colour

Tags: matlab, colors, set, pixel

**EDIT**

I have a `grayscale` image which contains pixel values of `300`, which I assigned manually to pixels that hold a specific criterion.

The case is that the other values in the image are `1` and `2`. So, I will have three values now: `1`, `2`, and `300`.

In order to display the image in a meaningful way, we can use `thresholding`. So, this is as for the pixels with values `1` and `2`. For the pixels with the value `300`, how can I assign it some colour to be able to discriminate it from other parts of the image.

Thanks.

Comment: as in RGB red (that is your image is MxNx3 matrix) or just mark them red in the figure? If your image is just  a 2-D matrix, then the colormap need to be edited in order fo pixel value 300 to be red. If your image is RGB then it is different.

Comment: @natan. Thanks for your comment. The image I'm using is `grayscale`. The goal actually is not to assign a `red` colour. But, a colour which I can discriminate such pixels from the other parts of the image. I made an **EDIT** to my question to clarify this

Comment: With my answer, you can set `opacity` on `[0,1]` and the pixel will be shaded red with that opacity.  Also, using `imshow` with a range (`[0 2]`) allows it to effectively threshold intensities in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values you have are `1,2,300` then a simple colormap will solve the issue. The trick is to assign the value `3` instead of `300` so the linear mapping of colormap can be used (1,2,3), for example, if your imagesc is called `im`:

```
im(im==300)=3;

cmap=[0.2 0.2 0.2; ...
      0.4 0.4 0.4; ...
      1   0   0  ];

colormap(cmap);
imagesc(im);
```

Here I created a 3-color colormap with colors for the 3 values (1 dark gray,2 lighter gray,3 red).

Answer (score 0):

To do this without modifying your image data, you can use the `AlphaData` property to make a color overlay at select locations.  Given a grayscale image `img`,

```
imshow(img, [0 2], 'InitialMag', 'fit'); hold on
red = cat(3, ones(size(img)), zeros(size(img)), zeros(size(img)));
h = imshow(red); hold off
opacity = 1.0;
set(h, 'AlphaData', opacity*double(img==300))
```

EDIT: If your other values are just 1 and 2, they will be very dark compared to 300, so the `[0 2]` in `imshow` will help with that.