# Assigning colours to regions of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, pixel

For an image I have, how can I do the following in `MATLAB`?

- Giving the pixels with values `100` for instance the colour `green`?
- Leaving the pixels with `0` as is. That is, keeping them `black`.
- Giving all other pixels the colour `red`.

**EDIT**

If I now know that pixels with value `255` are white, `0` are black. How can I assign the `red` colour to pixels with value `255`, and to all other pixels the colour `green`? Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving specific pixels a certain colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061400/giving-specific-pixels-a-certain-colour)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a colormap.
Assuming your image is of type `uint8`, you can create a map of 256 colors:

```
myMap = repmat( [1 0 0], [256,1] ); % make it all red
myMap(1,:) = 0; % make first color black
myMap(100,:) = [0 1 0]; % green for 100
cimg = ind2rgb( uint8im, myMap ); % convert to color according to map
```

Comment: @Simplicity you are correct. `ind2rgb` assumes the input image is a maped image. type `doc ind2rgb` for more help.

Comment: @ Shai. What should I do in this case to get the output? Thanks

Comment: If your input is axbxc, what do you expect the output size?

Comment: @Simplicity if your image has 3 color channels, what exactly do you mean by "pixels with value 100"? at which channel? one of them? all of them?

Comment: @Simplicity convert your image to gray using `rgb2gray` you'll end up with axb image, check what are the values for "gray" and "white" using `impixelinfo` and then you can use my answer. You might want to look at [`label2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/label2rgb.html).

Comment: @Shai. I have converted the image to `grayscale`. If I now know that pixels with value `255` are white, `0`, black. How can I mention to assign the `red` colour to pixels with value `255`, and to all other pixels the colour `red`? Thanks

Comment: I meant to say all other pixels the colour `green`

Comment: @Simplicity `myMap = repmat( [0 1 0], [256 1] );myMap(1,:) = 0;myMap(end,:) = [1 0 0]; cimg = in2rgb( im2uint8(grayImg), myMap );`

Comment: @Shai. I think it is almost working, except that the background which is supposed to be `black` is `green`! Why is that?

Comment: @Shai. Just a small typo in your last comment. `in2rgb` ---> `ind2rgb`

Comment: @Simplicity your black is not 100% black. use `impixelinfo` to explore.

Comment: @Shai. `This is an edit to the comment before the last comment`. For the background pixels, I don't get them all with the colour `black`